# Passing a custom message before an unload event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, firefox-browser-api

A window’s `onbeforeunload` property may be set to a function that returns a string that is shown to the user in a dialog box to confirm that the user wants to navigate away. This was intended to prevent users from losing data during navigation. Unfortunately, it is often used to scam users.

Starting in Chrome 51, a custom string will no longer be shown to the user. Chrome will still show a dialog to prevent users from losing data, but it's contents will be set by the browser instead of the web page.

With this change, Chrome will be consistent with Safari 9.1 and later, as well as Firefox 4 and later.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = 'Please Save or Submit changes before moving away from this page';
    confirmationMessage += 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.       
});
```

Is there a work around to pass custom message beforeunload event?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. If there were, it would rather defeat the purpose of the changes the browser vendors made, eh?

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial work-around possible in some browsers. You can't change the dialog, but you can try to change the page content before the dialog appears, to put up a big bold message that the user will see.

Here's a simple example which sort-of works in Firefox, but not in Chrome:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  document.body.textContent = "If you click leave you'll lose your data!";
  document.body.style.paddingTop = '40px';
  document.body.style.fontSize = '60px';
  document.body.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  return event.returnValue = 'warning';
});
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">a link to somewhere else</a>
```

[image]

You can see that the browser dims the page content, so the message isn't very prominent.